# issue posting #microsoft.graph.exclusionGroupAssignmentTarget

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

attempting to add an exclusion group via the api in graph explorer.

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/da91e7e4-47cf-490a-9b23-4cecacf69d93/assignments

request body

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.exclusionGroupAssignmentTarget",
    "groupId": "c16283f1-fb74-4e6c-9fc9-27b213b50512"
}
```

response preview

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ModelValidationFailure",
        "message": "Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'microsoft.management.services.api.exclusionGroupAssignmentTarget' was found to be of kind 'Complex' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Incompatible type kinds were found. The type 'microsoft.management.services.api.exclusionGroupAssignmentTarget' was found to be of kind 'Complex' instead of the expected kind 'Entity'.",
            "date": "2021-10-01T18:10:01",
            "request-id": "96cff9fa-bafd-4f87-98e5-69ff814faa8d",
            "client-request-id": "f8011c1f-1457-22ae-2e1e-e20842ccec11"
        }
    }
}
```